# Hacking Clang's rewriter?

Tags: html, clang, mediawiki

The [MediaWiki format](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aFormatting) is complicated and combined with various paradigms and grammar, and it was said to be impossible to convert without php and MediaWiki itself.

Is it possible to rewrite MediaWiki texts into HTML with hackings on Clang Rewriter? Could Clang somehow be hacked to recursively interpolate those templates?

EDIT:
I'm not expecting a perfect result, just wonder if this could be plausible.

Comment: It's not impossible, but it would be very difficult, if you want to have exactly the same output as Wikipedia. (And you do want that, because some templates rely on the exact rules.) And I doubt Clang Rewriter (though I have no idea what that is) changes anything about that.

Comment: Isn't Clang intended to work with C/C++/ObjC code? And Mediawiki format and HTML are not C/C++ code.

Comment: That's why I am asking if it is possible to hack it into accepting these. And MediaWiki format is NOT HTML, but rewriting it to HTML do require a robust parser, which Clang supplies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt Clang would be helpful; it really, really, wants to be compiler for C-like languages.  In particular, I understand it has a hand-written parser for C/C++/ObjectiveC, and I doubt that it would make any sense to try to bend that parser.   After parsing, you need to represent the program; Clang's AST classes are really, really intended to model its target languages.

I think what you want is a program transformation system.  These tools are designed to let you provide grammars for arbitrary languages, and use source-to-source rewrites to make changes.

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit is one of these.  It provides very strong parsing support; it can parse a wide variety languages including IBM COBOL, Java, HTML, C++, and Verilog to give an idea of its span.  It accepts multiple language definitions at once; this allows you write source-to-source transformations that map one language to another, which seems to be what you want to do.  (The source-to-source transformations idea works pretty well, and other PTS are pure source-to-source, but as a practical matter, implementing a translation tool with pure s-to-s is a little awkward; because not everything you need to do is rewrite.  DMS combines procedural code to compute inferences and s-to-s to achieve its effects).

Building a real translator for complex circumstances (as you seem to want to do) isn't easy even with PTS.  Just a lot more practical than trying to bend the wrong machinery to the job.

As other commenters have observed, you also have the additional task of reverse-engineering the actual mapping from MediaWiki input to HTML.

Comment: Isn't Wikipedia open source?  Why can't you just *use* what they are using?